# Converting C to Java

Tags: java, arrays, size

I'm in the process of converting C code to Java. I'm having a little trouble doing it:

C code:

```
char arr[100] = { 'A',B','C','D' };
  int n;
  scanf("%i", &n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%s",&arr[i]);
  }
```

Here's what I've done:

Java code:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String inputs = br.readLine();
    String tmp = br.readLine();
    int length = tmp.length();
    char c[] = new char[length];
    tmp.getChars(0, Integer.parseInt(inputs), c, 0);
    CharArrayReader in = new CharArrayReader(c);
    tmp = tmp.toLowerCase();
```

The only line I need to convert is:

```
 char arr[100] = { 'A','B','C','D' };
```

How do I convert that to Java?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
char arr[] = new char[100];
arr[0] = 'C';
arr[1] = 'L'; 
arr[2] = 'R'; 
arr[3] = 'S';
```

This will declare a char sized 100, and put the first 4 values as the ones you indicated. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It's always nice to have choices...

```
char[] arr=Arrays.copyOf(new char[] {  'A','B','C','D' },100);
```